# wordpress is stripping double prime (quote marks) from image title

Tags: images

When uploading images with a title like

**TestTwo Towers 2018 • 34"h x 8.5"w x 11"d.jpg**,

I end up with

**TestTwo Towers 2018 • 34h x 8.5w x 11d**.

Then file url to this image is

**/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/TestTwo-Towers-2018-•-3422h-x-8.522w-x-1122d.jpg**
and the file name is

**TestTwo-Towers-2018-•-3422h-x-8.522w-x-1122d.jpg.**

I am adding these to Smart Slider and they do not show quote marks (inches) unless I edit the title via the Media Library.

Does WP inherently strip quote marks from image titles? They are stripped before bringing them into Smart Slider.